Software to monitor real-time disk load in percents on Linux
Basically what Windows has in its process monitor

Disk load (not space on the disk) by system and all programs in percents.
Would be awesome if it also showed other stats like CPU usage, RAM etc. alongside, but I can use htop for that.
I've seen this and this posts, but the program there displays a lot of weird numbers and I need just percents.
So simple, terminal or GUI (bonus point) based, real-time disk load monitor in percents.

I like the Gnome System-Monitor Next Extension (GUI Widget). Not exactly what you want, but still worth a look.

Yeah, it's nice. Although I don't get to have the applet, because I use KDE Plasma, the app itself I might use instead of default KDE one (it also doesn't have disk load in percents, and disk load in any form in default layout)

iotop is cli tool you could try.

Htop has meter for that - you can add it via F2 then make search for "Disk IO" among meters on right


Mission Center from Flathub is a Windows-like process monitor that also has stupid simple disk usage in percents.
